# mysql query to find html tag element in database

Tags: html, mysql, tags

I want to query html in mysql i.e. 
I have record in table say x with info feild value  `<p>y</p>` . How can I query to match if `<p>y</p>` is present in that table .

```
select * from x where info="<p>y</p>";
```

is it only possible with full-text search or is there any other method too.

Comment: What are you mean with full-text search? Is `info like "%<p>y</p>%"` what you searching for?

Comment: If that's the whole field value, why doesn't `info="<p>y</p>"` work for you?

Comment: info="<p>y</p>" works only using mysql query but when using with php it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM x WHERE info LIKE '%<p>y</p>%';` is the only thing you **can** do to match such a string. Full-text search indexes work quite differently and are not suitable for the task. But this `LIKE` statement is very inefficient: it has to scan every matching row.